# Standard form elements, where to place the code in MVC architecture

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm in the creation of my own CMS. I'm doing this with the help of an MVC framework. I think a CMS should be build with a set of standard elements. Like, buttons, textfields and div containers where all the form elements reside in etc.

For instance, when i want to create a basic page then i want to do something like this in a view:

```
$cmsForm->beginTab('tab name');
$cmsForm->textfield('name', 'default value');
$cmsForm->textfield('email', '');
$cmsForm->textarea('info', '');
$cmsForm->submit('Save');
$cmsForm->endTab();
```

The problem is, is that i'm not sure where to put these methods. I obviously can't put these methods inside a controller. But perhaps a model is a good place? On the other hand, the model layer is used for storing/retrieving data from a persisten layer, not for returning HTML...

What would be a good place in an MVC architexture for this kind of thing?

Comment: create your own html helper class or use something included in the framework you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of code belongs in your view layer. Remember, there's no rule that says your view layer can only be templates.

Comment: So are you suggesting i should make a (helper) class in my View layer, which has methods like i described in opening post? And is it then my controllers job to pass an instance of that helper class to my view? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. It is a common way also to abstract logic out of your templates as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's no rule that says what you have to do.

If I was you, I'd write my own class and implement it in framework, because it would be easier to re-factor later in case you need it. Also you won't change the logic of framework accidentally (everything may happen).

Answer (score 1):

> On the other hand, the model layer is used for storing/retrieving data from a persisten layer, not for returning HTML

Actually model layer is for business logic.

---

This clearly is code related to presentation logic, and thus should be in the View. Thought i think, that instead of such strange generator script, you would be better off by writing a [template](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html), which view then handles.

Also, your API is horrible. Haven't you even heard about [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

If would be much better (but still misguided, IMHO )to have something like:

```
$foo = new HTML\Form();

$name = new HTML\Input('name');
$name->setValue('default value');
$name->setRules(array('required'));
$foo->addField( $name );

$email = new HTML\Input('email');
$email->setRules(array('required', 'email'));
$foo->addField( $email )

// other fields added

$template = new Template('/path/to/template.something');
$template->bind('form', $foo);
$output = $template->render();
```